# How to define an unconventional (?) One to many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relationship

I need to use a database where I have two tables, `Proprietaires` and `Certification`.

`Proprietaires` has these columns:

- Id
- IdCertification
- Name
- ...

`Certification` has these columns:

- Id
- ProprietaireId
- Name
- ...

So I've defined my `Proprietaire` entity like this :

```
public class Proprietaire
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdCertification { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Certification> Certifications { get; private set; } = new List<Certification>();
}
```

And `Certification` entity:

```
public class Certification
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProprietaireId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Proprietaire Proprietaire { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know to define relationship to have the following behavior :

When I access the `Proprietaire` property of my `Certification` entity, I need to get the `Proprietaire` where `Proprietaire.Id == Certification.ProprietaireId`. This part works.

But when I access the `Certifications` (list) property of my `Proprietaire` entity, I need to get all the certification

```
where Certification.ProprietaireId == Proprietaire.IdCertification
```

I don't even know if it possible with EF. But the database is not well structured, but I need to do with it ...

Is there a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: If you have an existing database, have you considered using Database-first? EF6 supports database-first using code-gen tools you then generate equivalent code-first entity classes. Are you using EF6 or EFCore?

Comment: I'm using EF6. I don't use Database first because the project already existed before I'm working on it and everything was done in Code first. But even in Database first, there is no constraint defined in database, so it would not help. No regret ^^